# Is it possible to run a two infinite while loops at the same time in python

Tags: python

I have made a timer while loop using

```
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       timeClock += 1
```

is it possible to execute this loop while executing another infinite while loop at the same time in the same program because I have made a command to show the elapsed time whenever I want
The whole Code is

```
def clock():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        t += 1 
        print(t)

clock()
while True:
    userInput = input("Do you want to know the total time this porgram has been running?\n Y for yes, N for no : ")
    if userInput == Y:
        print(t)
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need mutli-threading for this. You can also check the time difference between each input.

Comment: This is completely unnecessary; instead of trying to create your own clock (which will not be accurate because it the part of the code which sleeps takes longer than 0 seconds), just `import time`, do `start_time = time.monotonic()` at the start of the program, and then `int(time.monotonic() - start_time)` to get the current value of the timer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a very similar thing with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def clock(t):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        t.value += 1

t = Value('i', 0)
p = Process(target=clock, args=[t])
p.start()

while True:
    userInput = input("Do you want to know the total time this porgram has been running?\n Y for yes, N for no : ")
    if userInput == 'Y':
        print(t.value)
```

Multiprocessing has more overhead than multithreading, but it can often make better use of your machine's capabilities as it is truly running two or more processes in parallel.  Python's multithreading really doesn't, due to the dreaded GIL.  To understand that, [check this out](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple loops running at the same time, you should use multi-threading. This can be done using the `threading` library as shown below:

```py
import threading
import time

def clock():
    global t
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        t += 1 
        print(t)

x = threading.Thread(target=clock)
x.start()

t = 0

while True:
    userInput = input("Do you want to know the total time this porgram has been running?\n Y for yes, N for no : ")
    if userInput == 'Y':
        print(t)
    else:
        pass
```

If the only purpose is a clock however, you'd be better off following kaya's advice and using the time library itself.

Comment: why is this program taking '1 as an input on it's own?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed sorry I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: When I run this program it says `("Do you want to know the total time this porgram has been running?\n Y for yes, N for no : "` Then it automatically prints `1` as input and starts printing 1..2..3..4.etc. That's not how it is supposed to run is it?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed Ah I see what you mean, I was just adapting OP's code as much as possible. It's simple to remove the `print(t)` within the clock function.